# Ways to convert String to Spring Resource

Tags: string, spring, resources

I have a class with a resource property of type Resource in spring (`org.springframework.core.io.Resource`) which takes a file object as input.

```
setResource(Resource resource) 
  {
     this.resource = resource;
  }
```

However, I am reading a remote document through another custom API which returns the contents of the document as a String.

```
String xml = document.getContent();
```

I want to pass this xml as `Resource` in my `setResource` method. However, I don't know how can I cast String into `Resource`.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 38):

You can create a `ByteArrayResource` from the String:

```
String xml = document.getContent();
Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(xml.getBytes());
setResource(resource);
```

Comment: Thanks!! That helped.. why it is not advisable to use setResource(new InMemoryResource(xml)) ??

Comment: @Nikunj: Because `InMemoryResource` isn't part of Spring, It's part of Spring Security.  if you have that, though, then it would work fine.